# one-click script o backup and restore individual registry keys

Tags: windows-8, backup, windows-registry, powershell

I have an application that stores some settings in registry. For whatever reason, it loses some stuff on occasion. I don't really have time to figure out what the problem is (it's not even guaranteed that I could) so I'd like to make a one-click shortcut to backup and restore specific keys. I would imagine that this is a job for powershell. Could somebody please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Reg Export command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742017.aspx) to export the key and [Reg import](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742021.aspx) to import the data. Put this into a CMD batch file which you can start with 1 click.

Comment: Shorter than this, in fact - a shortcut works just as well. Thanks!